# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' error in lamba

Tags: python, regex, pandas, lambda

I'm trying to use a regex to extract part of a string from a pandas column. However, the code results in an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Here is the code I used:

```
dff['User_Mentions'] = dff['content'].apply(lambda x: re.search("@([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15})", x).group(1))
```

Comment: if there is no match, `re.search` returns `None`. [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) might be more appropriate for what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `re.search` in this way there need to be a match at each row, otherwise `None` is returned. Since `None` does not have a `group` attribute you will see the current error.

One way to avoid the error would be to change the pattern slightly and use an empty alternative using `|$`:

```
dff['User_Mentions'] =  dff['content'].apply(lambda x: re.search("@([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15})|$", x).group(1))
```

This will give a `None` value in the dataframe when there is no match.

---

Another alternative would be to use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) as mentioned in a comment:

```
dff['User_Mentions2'] =  dff['content'].str.extract('@([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15})', expand=False)
```

This would instead result in a `NaN` value in the rows with no match.